# Is there a way to convert my column of incrementing integers separated by zero to the number of intervals encountered so far in a pandas datafram?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm working in pandas and I have a column in my dataframe filled by 0s and incrementing integers starting at one. I would like to add another column of integers but that column would be a counter of how many intervals separated by zero we have encountered to this point. For example my data would like like

```py
Index
1
2
3
0
1
2
0
1
```

and I would like it to look like

```py
Index IntervalCount
1     1
2     1
3     1
0     1
1     2 
2     2
0     2
1     2
```

Is it possible to do this with vectorized operation or do I have to do this iteratively? Note, it's not important that it be a new column could also overwrite the old one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) function.

`df["IntervalCount"] = (df["Index"] == 1).cumsum()`